# How to resolve Snapshot isolation transaction aborted error in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, transactions

We are using hibernate to update value of a table then I got below error

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper | Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. You cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'dev.TASKS' directly or indirectly in database 'DEV' to update, delete, or insert the row that has been modified or deleted by another transaction. Retry the transaction or change the isolation level for the update/delete statement.
```

We are using hibernate 4.3.11 and SQLServer 2014 as our database.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent anomalies, the database has two options:

1. It can prevent them, by using locking.
2. It can allow conflicts, but it needs to detect them on transaction commit.

Traditionally, [2PL (Two-Phase Locking)](https://vladmihalcea.com/write-skew-2pl-mvcc/) was the defacto standard for providing Strict Serializability. But, although this allows you to prevent all types of phenomena, it does not scale.

Because of the scaling issue, databases have opted for concurrency control mechanisms that do less locking, like [MVCC](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-mvcc-multi-version-concurrency-control-work/). But in MVCC, a concurrent transaction is allowed to modify the records that you have previously read. And, when you try to commit, you are going to get a transaction abort.

Therefore, you can fix it in two ways:

1. If there is less concurrency, you can use pessimistic locking like the JPA [PESSIMISTIC_READ and PESSIMISTIC_WRITE](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/). Once you acquire the lock on the entity that you need to change, no other transaction can modify it, so they'll have to wait for you to release the lock.
2. You can do as suggested by the exception, by retrying.

Retrying is, however, trickier. You can't retry if you get a constraint violation or if your transaction should only proceed if some rows do not modify.

However, restarting a workflow is not that bad as it sounds. This is the only way to [prevent a lost update over multiple physical database transactions](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

So, although it would be wonderful for Hibernate to offer a setting to magically fix this issue, that would be the wrong thing to do. The reason why the transaction is aborted is [to avoid breaking ACID guarantees](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/).

So, you should review why the conflict happens, and decide whether either locking or retrying the workflow work better for your particular application use case.